# why using same variable as index variable in nested 'for' loops doesn't throw an warning?

Tags: c, eclipse, visual-c++

I am using eclipse IDE and MSVC for my C development.
I noticed that the compiler doesn't give warning for using same index variable in nested for loops.

Why doesn't it give warning and how can i detect such potential programming faults?

Regards,
Sreenivasa

Comment: I don't know for `MSVC` but `gcc` `-Wshadow` can warn about that, so i guess there could be a flag for `MSVC`.

Answer (score 1):

If a variable declared in a block and it is redeclared in an enclosing block, then new declaration temporarily hides the previous declaration.

```
int a[5][5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    { 
        //Previous i is not visible 
        scanf("%d", &a[i][i]); 
    }
    //No knowledge of i in inner loop. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such warning in MSVC. Even if you compile with /Wall, and include all the warnings that are off by default (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23k5d385.aspx), you will not get a warning for declaring a variable with the same name in a child scope. Some static code analyzers will report these sorts of errors, I would suggest using one, or cross compiling with another compiler to get better coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this today, in a function that I was porting from standard C to C++. Although I haven't yet done any serious research, I suspect that no warning is issued because defining a like named variable in an interior scope is considered legal. This caught me off guard, leading to several hours wasted trying to figure out why a do-while loop that should have met its termination condition was executing infinitely.

The reason that I was off guard is that the Visual C# compiler emits a warning when you do this. The C# warning is pretty specific; you just hid a variable Foo declared in an outer block. After some effort, I have confirmed that the very latest Visual C++ compiler still behaves this way.

I like the C# approach; allow it, but issue a warning.